# How to log the average values of memory and cpu usage

Tags: 20.04, log

I want to create a script which calculate the average ram and cpu usage for a period of time,for example 2 minutes and then pass those values to a file.Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64bit and GNOME version 3.36.8

Comment: Look for "files" under `/proc`. Instant memory information is in `/proc/meminfo` for example. CPU "usage" (?) may be more complicated.

Comment: `uptime` prints the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes. Maybe it helps :-)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli i will check it.Thank you!